# Firefox save password, based on page or based on field names

Tags: html, firefox, browser, passwords

I tried to search the answer but can't get anything related to this.

Here is my problem, on create account page of the site, firefox can ask the user to save the password. If user click on save. In firefox settings -> saved passwords, I can see a record with the right username.

Then I go to the sign page of the same site, it won't populate any saved password. If I enter the same username and password as before and click on sign in. This time we can save the password again. After this in firefox settings -> saved passwords, now I can see 2 records with the same user name.

And this time if I go to the sign in page again, the saved username and password will populate correctly.

My question is, for these 2 records in saved passwords(they look exactly the same, shows same site url with the same username). Firefox will find the right username and password in saved passwords based on the page? Or based on the field name on the page? If someone knows, please tell me a little more, thank you very much.

Comment: I tried to created 2 test pages in a site. They have different field names and they are different pages. Still firefox was be able to save the password on one page and use it on the other, so there could be something wrong for my site pages.... Does anyone has any idea what could be wrong? Thank you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often the initial signup fields will have different names than the login fields. This causes the browser to not recognize that they are the same fields. When you save the first time it saves the signup credentials connected to the signup form, when you save the second time it saves the login credentials connected to the login form. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: I think you are right, I did multiple tests, finally find out there was a big security issue with the site, the sign in page is a https page, but the form actually points to and http address... So it won't recognize it if the form action use different protocols.

I created 2 pages to test this when both page are https, the password you saved it shows the same in saved password, but if one form's action points to https address another points to http, the saved password will not populate.  Thank you. :D